# Java8 Try-with-resource/JDBC/Play Framework: Is this correct?

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework, try-with-resources

I have rewritten a Play2/JDBC query using try-with-resources, but I'm not sure, if this is correct.
The first try block handles the Connection and PrepareStatement. The second try handles the ResultSet.

Theoretically the connection, the statement and the resultset will be closed correctly in any case? Is that right? Or do I miss something that needs to be handled?

```
public static List<Item> findBySimpleSQL(String where, java.lang.Object... params) {
  List<Item> collection = new ArrayList<Item>();
  try (Connection connection = play.db.DB.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM items WHERE "+where);)
  {
    int pos = 1;
    for (java.lang.Object o : params) {
      if (o instanceof Integer) {pstmt.setInt(pos, (int) o);}
      if (o instanceof Long) {pstmt.setLong(pos, (long) o);}
      if (o instanceof String) {pstmt.setString(pos, (String) o);}
      pos++;
    }
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
      while (rs.next()) collection.add(parse(rs));
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.error("Error message: "+e);
  }
  return collection;
}
```

-- Added logging to the catch block.

Comment: One thing is certainly wrong: Never leave a `catch` block empty.

Comment: ...especially if it catches just Excepion

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle's [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

> "A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is
> finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each
> resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that
> implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which
> implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource."

In your case the `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` all implement the `AutoCloseable` interface, so the answer is:

Yes, they will be closed correctly(not sure about ANY case, coding and absolutes don't get along very well).

You might want to read the aforementioned link and make sure you correctly catch the possible exceptions.

Comment: I checked out the link "try-with-resources". There is an example showing JDBC usage. Now I wonder why they don't put the ResultSet in a try-with-resourses block. Some people say you'll have to close the ResultSet but then I found this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29 . So it seems that the try block around the ResultSet is unnecessary. Any comment?

Comment: Well, again, it depends. Imagine you want to reuse the precompiled PreparedStatement after you're done with the ResultSet. In such a case the ResultSet should be put in it's own try-with-resource. Or maybe the PreparedStatement is parametriezed and used in a for-loop... or... or.

Comment: The interactions between Connections, Statements and ResultSets are not as linear as one might think. One should also take into account the JDBC driver implementation AND the fact that conn, stmt and rs are garbage collected(at least they were...).

Comment: Do you need additional clarifications? Or we can close this?